# How to add version as comment in scss file dynamically

Tags: node.js, github, version-control, sass

I have an scss file in my node project.

I also have a package.json file that contains the current version of my project which gets updated everytime I make new release on Github :

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
  "version": "3.0.1",
  ....
}
```

I want the version to appear as a CSS comment in my scss file at the top, e.g.

**project.scss**

```
/* Project Name - 3.0.1 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.....
....
..
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: Do you want the comment to appear on scss file or the build file? or both?

Comment: On the build file